# Possible to have check boxes already checked when user clicks on google map website?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, checkbox

I have created a google map with multiple layers with checkboxes so that the user can toggle back and forth on the layers. Currently, when the user opens the map, the layers are already on and the checkboxes are unchecked. How can I change my code so that when the user opens the map, the checkboxes are checked and the layers are on (and then the user can uncheck the checkboxes to take off layers). Basically: if checked, show layer. If unchecked, do not show layer

My website: http://userpages.flemingc.on.ca/~eluli/example.html

My Javascript code:

```
var map, layer2, layers;
layers = [];
function initialize() {
    var ontario = new google.maps.LatLng(49.2867873, -84.7493416);

var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 5,
        center: ontario,
styles: [{"featureType":"landscape.natural","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"visibility":"on"},{"color":"#e0efef"}]},{"featureType":"poi","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"visibility":"on"},{"hue":"#1900ff"},{"color":"#c0e8e8"}]},{"featureType":"road","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"lightness":100},{"visibility":"simplified"}]},{"featureType":"road","elementType":"labels","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"transit.line","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"visibility":"on"},{"lightness":700}]},{"featureType":"water","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"color":"#7dcdcd"}]}]
    }

    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var openInfoWindow = function (KMLevent) {
        infoWindow.close();
        infoWindow.setOptions(
        {
            content: KMLevent.featureData.infoWindowHtml,
            position: KMLevent.latLng,
            pixelOffset: KMLevent.pixelOffset
        });
        infoWindow.open(map);
    };

     map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

    var kmlOptions = {
        suppressInfoWindows: true,  // do not to display an info window when clicked
        preserveViewport: false,
        map: map
    };



  //Layer 0 is NDP       
         layers [0] = new google.maps.KmlLayer('https://docs.google.com/uc?authuser=0&id=0B79b02nBK5vkRGo1RlpVVW4td1k&export=download',
 {preserveViewport: false, suppressInfoWindows: true});
      //Layer 1 is Liberal    
        layers [1] = new google.maps.KmlLayer('https://docs.google.com/uc?authuser=0&id=0B79b02nBK5vkdXd6aWFZc05uaWM&export=download',
 {preserveViewport: false, suppressInfoWindows: true});
        //Layer 2 is PC1 
        layers [2] = new google.maps.KmlLayer('https://docs.google.com/uc?authuser=0&id=0B79b02nBK5vkYjhLenRqVWVuR0U&export=download',
 {preserveViewport: false, suppressInfoWindows: true});
// Layer 3 PC2
        layers [3] = new google.maps.KmlLayer('https://docs.google.com/uc?authuser=0&id=0B79b02nBK5vkSlJZSDR2MzBOY1E&export=download',
 {preserveViewport: false, suppressInfoWindows: true});

        //Layer 4 PC3
        layers [4] = new google.maps.KmlLayer('https://docs.google.com/uc?authuser=0&id=0B79b02nBK5vkSjNrck1MZmMydlE&export=download',
 {preserveViewport: false, suppressInfoWindows: true});
        //layer 5 Schools
        layers [5] = new google.maps.KmlLayer('https://docs.google.com/uc?authuser=0&id=0B79b02nBK5vkajc2OGZTZDZBV0k&export=download',
 {preserveViewport: false, suppressInfoWindows: true});


  for (var i = 0; i < layers.length; i++) {
        layers[i].setMap(null);
      }



    layer2 = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
    query: {
      select: 'col9',
      from: '1FzRSqRcxY37i7VtejqONHhAB-MrzFhakYSvZaIvo'
    }
  });
  layer2.setMap(map);

   // Pop-up window
    layers.forEach(function(url) {
        var layer = new google.maps.KmlLayer(url, kmlOptions);
        layer.setMap(map);
        google.maps.event.addListener(layer, "click", openInfoWindow);

    });

}


function toggleLayer(i) {
  if (layers[i].getMap() === null) {
    layers[i].setMap(map);
  }
  else {
    layers[i].setMap(null);
  }
}

//initialize();
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

My HTML:

```
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
    <div id="checkboxes">
  <input type="checkbox" id="layer0" onclick="toggleLayer(0)">NDP <br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="layer1" onclick="toggleLayer(1)">Liberal <br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="layer2" onclick="toggleLayer(2)">PC1 <br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="layer3" onclick="toggleLayer(3)">PC2 <br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="layer4" onclick="toggleLayer(4)">PC3 <br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="layer5" onclick="toggleLayer(5)">Schools 
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
   html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
}
   #checkboxes {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  right: 10px;
  font-family: 'arial', 'sans-serif';
  font-size: 14px;
  background-color: white;
    border-width:5px;   
    border-style:groove;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `checked="checked"` to all your checkboxes, like follows:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="layer0" onclick="toggleLayer(0)" checked="checked">NDP <br>
```

Comment: I did that but when I uncheck the boxes, the layers still show (in fact, they are highlighted)

Comment: I was experimenting with the code and I realized that if I comment out the pop up window code section, the layers turn on and off as I click the checkboxes. However, I need the pop up window in my map